# Probability with ordered groups

Tags: probability

Problem:

a1, a2, a3, a4

b1, b2, b3

c1, c2

how many possible out comes are there with the constraint that a2 comes after a1 a3 comes after a2 ... c2 comes after c1.
so some possible outcomes are:
a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2
a1 a2 b1 b2 b3 c1 a3 a4 c2

Ive tried a lot of different approaches (mainly brute forcing on a small scale to find a pattern) but cant find anything that works.
I know a little about statistic but not enough to know how to do this problem i think.  i have learned about combinations and permutation but dont know how to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that you mean one sequence of $9$ letters with the given restriction.

$1.$ Place $a1-a2-a3-a4$ in sequence in any $4$ of $9$ spots in line in $\binom94$ ways.

$2.$ Place $b1-b2-b3$ in sequence in the remaining $5$ spots in $\binom53$ ways

$3.$ Place $c1-c2$ in sequence in the $2$ remaining spots.

Thus ans $= \binom94\binom53$